# Ignore meaningless "Merge branch" commits in Git history?

Tags: git

Please take a look at the following Git history:

[image]

About every second commit is meaningless "Merge branch" noise. I know that you can (and should) avoid it by rebasing, but my question is more about dealing with the situation afterwards.

**Is there a trick to ignore "Merge branch" commits without information?**

It would be acceptable for me to clone the repository and locally rewrite its history, so it is easier to analyze its changes (without all the "Merge branch" noise).

Comment: `git log --no-merges` should do the trick

Comment: @BroiSatse Yes, that is exactly what it need. :-) Please post it as an answer. I will accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for

```
git log --no-merges
```

Answer (score 2):

BroiSatse's nice "git log --no-merges" trick can also be applied in gitk:

- View -> Edit view -> Additional arguments to git log: "--no-merges"

The result looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

to avoid having a lot of merges, it is better to pull using rebase:

```
git pull --rebase
```

see [docs](http://gitready.com/advanced/2009/02/11/pull-with-rebase.html) here